# Whats the percentage of somebody getting homework in class

Tags: probability

there is a 25% chance you get homework in one class 
there is a 40% chance you get homework in another class
what is the probability you get homework in both classes

Comment: There's not enough information to answer the question. Perhaps you intended to imply that the two events of getting homework in the two classes are independent?

Answer (score 2):

it is between 0 and 0.25, based on the information you have given. However, if you assume they are independent. i.e. they are two teachers who do not disccuss whether they should give home work on the same day or not

then P(A and B) = P(A)P(B) = 0.25 * 0.4 = 0.1

A is getting work from the 1st class, B is getting work from the 2nd class.